# How to update list values on initstate in flutter?

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

I want to update the **newList** when the state gets initiated and want to store api response into that list.

```
class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
List newList = [];
  getSlideBanners() async {

    var resp = await http.get(Uri.parse("xxx"));

    newList.addAll(jsonDecode(resp.body));

    return jsonDecode(resp.body);
  }

}
```

Comment: call your function in `initState` , and dont forget to `setState` your `newList`

Comment: Solved sir.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way also :

```
@override
void initState() {
  getSlideBanners();
  
  super.initState();
}

getSlideBanners() async {

    var resp = await http.get(Uri.parse("xxx"));

    newList.addAll(jsonDecode(resp.body));
     //here you can do setState 
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: can it be done using getter and setter ? I am new to Object Oriented coding so bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Future method will take some time to fetch, you can do it like

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  getSlideBanners().then(
    (value) {
      //here 
      setState(() {});
    },
  );
}
```